# Empty source tabs in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I open my file Java - I see ... nothing

[image]

but when I Restart Eclipse - all working again ... before it will not open another file of my project

**what happens? I can not restart eclipse every time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the root of your project and select `Refresh`. Maybe the files are out of sync with the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with installation of eclipse.I will suggest you to reinstall eclipse and adt plug in.